# How to include Server Role in SQL Server Audit or Audit specification to capture specific logins and actions?

Tags: sql-server, audit

In SQL Server I want to create a Server Audit to collect events for specific Server Roles only.
How can I include the Server Role in the Audit or Audit specification to include logins and actions only for specific logins belonging to specific server roles?

I created a custom server role named TestServerRole and added an existing login to it.

```
USE master;   
GO  
CREATE SERVER AUDIT AuditDataAccess  
    TO FILE ( FILEPATH ='C:\SQL Audits' )  
    WHERE object_name = 'SensitiveData' ;  
GO  
ALTER SERVER AUDIT AuditDataAccess WITH (STATE = ON);  
GO  
-- Create the database audit specification in the TestDB database  
USE TestDB;  
GO  
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [FilterForSensitiveData]  
FOR SERVER AUDIT [AuditDataAccess]   
ADD (SELECT ON SCHEMA::[DataSchema]  BY [public]),
**ADD (SELECT ON SCHEMA::[DataSchema]  BY [TestServerRole])**
WITH (STATE = ON);  
GO
```

When I filter by the TestServerRole server role I get an error.
"Cannot find the user 'TestServerRole', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

Ideally I would like to include all actions on all databases, too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Logins connect to database users in order to execute queries such as `SELECT`. So you would need to use a database level principal, either `ADD (SELECT ON SCHEMA::[DataSchema]  BY [SomeDatabaseRole])` or `ADD (SELECT ON SCHEMA::[DataSchema]  BY [SomeUser])`